# Why is .get() not working in my discord bot code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to change a channel's name to show the number of users in the guild. However, when I start up my bot, it says the following in the console:

> Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined

I narrowed the problem down to this line: `bot.channels.get("533334637163053077");`

Just in case you need it, here is my code:

```
const Discord=require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const PREFIX = "-";
const guildID = "418505146876559371";
let ref = require("./ref.json");
let request = require(`request`);
const memberCountChannel = bot.channels.get("533334637163053077"); //This one is the one
//that is not working I think
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

var servers = {};

bot.on('warn', console.warn);
bot.on('error', console.error);

bot.on('ready', function(guild)
{
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online with ${bot.users.size} 
    members.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n`);
    bot.user.setActivity('with the server. Type -help for info.');
    memberCountChannel.edit(`Members: ${guild.memberCount}`, 8000); //Change name of channel
});
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member){
    memberCountChannel.edit(`Members: ${guild.memberCount}`, 8000);//Change name of channel
});

bot.on("guildMemberRemove", async function(member){
    memberCountChannel.edit(`Members: ${guild.memberCount}`, 8000);//Change name of channel
});
bot.login('TOKEN HERE');
```

EDIT: The channel does exist and the bot does have privileges to do everything with the channel.

Comment: Probably the channel `533334637163053077` don't exists or you don't have permission to view it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I have already added the bot's role (which already has full administrator privileges) to the permissions tab and checked the green check mark for everything and i am still getting the error.

Comment: Try moving `memberCountChannel = bot.channels.get("533334637163053077");` into your on ready function, I think perhaps your trying to get the channel before the bot is even ready. So it would return undefined.

Comment: Thank you so much Pheonix, that fixed my problem!

Comment: Your whole code should actually be inside the `ready` event.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 Can you please write it in a new answer, so that the author can accept it and mark the question as closed? This will both give you reputation for your answer and help others find the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the issue was, as you correctly surmised with

`const memberCountChannel = bot.channels.get("533334637163053077");`

The reason for this is you are trying to call a method(.get) on an object (channels) that doesn't exist until the .on('ready') event is fired.